# Get a specific String After and Before a character

Tags: php, string, replace

For example if i hava a string

```
$string = 'haircut-with-shampoo-and-style-from-vibe-styling-salon';
```

And i have another string or character like

```
$string2 = 'sh'
```

Now i want to get exactly

```
$finalstr = 'shampoo'
```

by replacing previous and next string from '-'.

Is there anyway to do so? But i am unable to do so.

Comment: Your question is not too clear. Please can you be more descriptive on what you want done

Comment: Thanks for your time, But question is solved by Mr.Cr3aHal0 . ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the `$string` will always be  cut into "parts" with "-" ? Are you looking for words matching a specific prefix ?

If yes, you can compose an array with  `$string` :

`$array = explode("-", $string);`

then iterate over $array to compare your prefix with each word stored into $array (you will probably need REGEX)

Comment: You probably mean `explode()`

Comment: Yeah, $string will always cut with '-' And thanks for the answer I got you as @daan said you means to say explode() . And now i feel that how stupid i am that i don't even think about this simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to use a combination of `strstr` and `substr` with `strpos`:

```
$string = 'haircut-with-shampoo-and-style-from-vibe-styling-salon';
$string2 = 'sh';

$finalstr = substr(($str = strstr($string . '-', $string2)), 0, strpos($str, '-'));
echo $finalstr;
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/I9k7TP)

Sidenote: The added `-` is just in case for the `sa => salon` instance.

What this basically does is it just gets the first occurence of that needle from the main string (the segment), then from that segmented string, it just subtrstrings it into the first `-` dash thus getting the desired string.

However if you need to match multiple strings or matching inside the substring, the easiest route would be just to explode and test each:

```
$string = 'haircut-with-shampoo-and-style-from-vibe-styling-salon-sharon';
$string2 = 'sh';
$finalstr = ''; // $finalstr = array();
foreach(explode('-', $string) as $s) {
    if(stripos($s, $string2) !== false) {
        $finalstr .= ' ' . $s;
        // $finalstr[] = $s;
    }
}

echo $finalstr;
// echo implode(' ', $finalstr); // array option
```

Or array form version:

```
$string = 'haircut-with-shampoo-and-style-from-vibe-styling-salon-sharon';
$string2 = 'sh';
$finalstr = implode(' ', array_filter(explode('-', $string), function($s) use($string2){
    return stripos($s, $string2) !== false;
}));

echo $finalstr;
```

Comment: Actually i was looking to get whole matched sub string after -. like if 'on' should return 'salon'.

Comment: @king4aol yeah, if the case would be in the middle, you might need another route.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way if you're looking for something starting with `sh` that is surrounded by `-` or at the beginning or end of the string:

```
preg_match("/(\b|-)(sh[^\b-]+)(\b|-)/", $string , $match);
$finalstr = $match[2];
```

Comment: This won't work if the word he's looking for is at the end of the list or at the beginning (would need some quantifiers)